# Style to resize the column in free-jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

1. How to auto change the span size so that it is equal to a div? [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4otWn.png)
   [image]

```css
.ui-jqgrid tr.ui-jqgrid-labels  div {
      white-space: normal !important;  
}
```

[See here jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v6rvrjg0/8/).

2. There are such limitations in free-jqgrid 4.14.0? http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3Agroupingheadar

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use the following additional CSS rules

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th.ui-th-column {
    position: relative;
}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-labels > .ui-th-column > .ui-jqgrid-resize {
    top: 0;
    float: none;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-labels > .ui-th-ltr > .ui-jqgrid-resize {
    right: 1px;
}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-labels > .ui-th-rtl > .ui-jqgrid-resize {
    left: 1px;
}
```

see the modified demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/owypx8c5/1/. I added `direction: "rtl"` to the second grid to verify that new settings works with RTL languages too. I suppose it's not your case and you want remove it like in https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/owypx8c5/2/.

I will adjust `ui.jqgrid.css` to use the above settings as default CSS rules of free jqGrid.

Comment: A bug appears when using  **guiStyle: "bootstrap"** [link](https://jsfiddle.net/eqjr540e/3/)

Comment: @kostya: Which bug exactly you mean? What is expected results and what one has instead?

Comment: The title of the text floats down. But if you set the property   **useColSpanStyle: false** bug is gone

Comment: @kostya: One have to remove [the part](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.14.1/js/grid.custom.js#L1364-L1383) of code of `setGroupHeaders` to be able to use new CSS properties, which I suggested, together with the column groping (`setGroupHeaders` method). I made already the corresponding modification in the code of free jqGrid. I'll publish the changes to GitHub after some additional tests.

Comment: Thank you so much!